# Chrome Will Not Print

Tags: google-chrome, hplip

It'll go through the motions, with print head moving slower than normal, but spits blank page.  I have to print from Firefox every time.  I am printing in draft black with HPLIP & a HP Deskjet D1660.

I cannot find any relevant content on Google so have posted here in the hope someone knows how to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than finding the root cause of this probably-bug, try the PDF-workaround.

Print to a file (PDF) first, then print this PDF from your favourite PDF viewer.

[image]

Comment: Good workaround! I am yet to try printing from Chromium, (now using Chromium as Chrome had no sound via You Tube.)

Comment: Chromium prints just fine!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing chrome and then re-install it back.
chrome-stable version.

Comment: I recommend editing this answer to explain *how* to do that.

Comment: Already tried this.